# Help for Divergence operator

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm a newbie and may be this question is bit simple for you but pardon me if it's too simple.

1. Can some one tell me some **reference** to study about the **invertibility**  of Divergence operator  $\operatorname{div}\colon C^1(\omega)\to G$ where $G$ is a space of  real valued function and $\omega$ is a subset of $\Bbb R^2$. Here I assume a Dirichlet type condition on the boundary of $\omega$ is specified and all boundary and domain have nice smoothness.
2. In above context can someone give me some reference on the **Null space** structure of the divergence operator operating on differentiable maps defined on $\Bbb R^2$ ?

Ariwn

Comment: "curl"?  There is only such a thing (as a map from vector fields to vector fields) in $n=3$.

Comment: By curl you mean the exterior derivative acting on 1-form? And why should $G$ be a space of vector valued function?

Comment: Divergence takes vector fields to scalar fields.

Comment: Sorry for my typo  error and horrible english.I mean it maps vector valued maps to scalar valued and the curl of a map case in question 2 was for $R^3 (poincare type )$ but , here I need in $R^2$

Comment: Perhaps you want the analogue of [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) in two dimensions. I think this is dealt with in fluid mechanics in terms of the stream function and velocity potential, but I'm afraid I don't have a reference handy.

Answer (score 1):

A divergence-free vector field corresponds to an incompressible flow.  The null space is infinite-dimensional.  For example, to get a divergence-free vector field supported in a 
ball $\{|x| \le r\}$, you can take something like this:
$$V(x) = (f(|x|) x_2, -f(|x|) x_1, 0, \ldots, 0)$$
where $f$ is a smooth function supported in $[0,r]$.

Comment: Thank you for the reference.In general I need that if $\nabla \cdot q_1 = \nabla \cdot q_2 $  on $\Omega $ in $R^2$  then what I can conclude in general about the relationships of $q_1$ and $q_2$.To be more specific I need to find $q_1 \cdot e_i $ if $\nabla \cdot q_1 = 0 $ where $e_i$ is the unit normal vector in $R^2 $.

Comment: It could be any smooth function (subject to boundary conditions).  That is, given $v_1$ you can take $v_2$ to be a solution of $\dfrac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2} = - \dfrac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}$ and have $\nabla \cdot (v_1, v_2) = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Like Robert pointed out, this problem is related to Stokes problem, a limiting case of the incompressible Navier-Stokes equation.

For Arbitrary dimension as you first asked, you could refer to [this paper](http://www.dml.cz/bitstream/handle/10338.dmlcz/128452/CzechMathJ_44-1994-1_10.pdf), in $\mathbb{R}^3$, the existence of a vector potential to solve the divergence equation can be found [here](http://perso.univ-rennes1.fr/monique.dauge/publis/ABDG_VPot.pdf).

For $\mathbb{R}^2$, I am looking at the [book by Girault and Raviart](http://books.google.com/books/about/Finite_element_methods_for_Navier_Stokes.html) now, the complete results of the function spaces related to divergence operator can be found from page 22, and they are like an application of De Rham's work in cohomology.
$\newcommand{\v}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}$
Basic idea is for any smooth vector fields $\v{v}$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$, there exists a decomposition 
$$
\v{v} = \mathbf{grad} \phi + \mathbf{curl} \psi 
$$
if the boundary of domain of interest has certain smoothness(say Lipschitz). Say if your problem is to find $\v{v}$ such that 
$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{div} \v{v} &= f \text{ in } \Omega
\\
\v{v} &= \v{g} \text{ on } \partial\Omega
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Plugging the decomposition would enable you to establish a Neumann problem of Laplace equation for $\phi$, and any $\psi \in H^1$ that has a zero boundary condition would satisfy $\mathbf{curl} \psi \cdot \v{n} = 0$ on boundary.